# `javax.filter.Filter` not adding CORS headers correctly

Tags: java, tomcat

I have a simple `javax.filter.Filter` implementation that is supposed to add CORS headers to a `HttpResponse`:

```
    log.debug("Headers before adding: {}", response.getHeaderNames());
    log.debug("Adding CORS headers to {}", response.getClass().getName());
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET,POST,PUT,DELETE,OPTIONS");
    log.debug("Headers after adding: {}", response.getHeaderNames());
```

But, sometimes the headers don't end up in the response (according to both the receiving party and this bit of log):

```
DEBUG  Headers before adding: [Cache-Control]
DEBUG  Adding CORS headers to org.apache.catalina.connector.ResponseFacade
DEBUG  Headers after adding: [Cache-Control]
```

and sometimes they do:

```
DEBUG  Headers before adding: []
DEBUG  Adding CORS headers to org.apache.catalina.connector.ResponseFacade
DEBUG  Headers after adding: [Access-Control-Allow-Origin, Access-Control-Allow-Methods, Access-Control-Allow-Headers]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was, that if you call `chain.doFilter(req, res)` before setting headers, Tomcat/Jetty will start writing the response and cannot add any more headers. Unfortunately, neither server will give you an error message or exception to indicate that.

Solution: Always set the headers before calling `chain.doFilter(req, res)`